# What is the best approach to do this condition in SQL if user has a multiple activity and I only want to get a specific status

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Status will only show :

- Done - if there is at least 1 completed
- In Progress - if there is no any completed but at least 1 in progress
- Hold - if all activities is in hold

Sample Data :

```
MyTable       (TableName)

StatusColumn  (ColumnName)
  Done
  In Progress
  Hold
```

I'm thinking to use the CASE() function but I am quite confused since I'm still a beginner in SQL, or if there's any other approach that you guys can suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using Case Expresssion in Google BigQuery as :

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN StatusColumn = 'Done' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Done'
    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN StatusColumn = 'In Progress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'In Progress'
    ELSE 'Hold'
  END AS Status
FROM MyTable;
```

You can also do it using [COUNTIF function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#countif) too.

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN COUNTIF(StatusColumn = 'Done') > 0 THEN 'Done'
    WHEN COUNTIF(StatusColumn = 'In Progress') > 0 THEN 'In Progress'
    ELSE 'Hold'
  END AS Status
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks @Tushar the first answer with the SUM() function works however I tried the COUNTIF() and it display 'Hold' only?

Comment: @user21066109 : OK, Let me compare and check :)